# Matter.js- only bodyA passes through body B; but none of the other bodies pass through bodyA

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am working on learning and understanding the angry birds game. What I don't understand is why is my bird able to pass through the platform and the constrained logs that are connected to the bird, they get stuck at the edge of the platform. I want to understand why this collision only happens for the logs and the platform and not the bird and the platform. When I created a second bird body/object, that one even went behind the platform and could no longer be seen. Why is this happening please?

```js
class BaseClass{
    constructor(x, y, width, height, angle) {
        var options = {
            'restitution':0.8,
            'friction':1.0,
            'density':1.0
        }
        this.body = Bodies.rectangle(x, y, width, height, options);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        World.add(world, this.body);
      }
      display(){
        var angle = this.body.angle;
        push();
        translate(this.body.position.x, this.body.position.y);
        rotate(angle);
        rectMode(CENTER);
        rect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
        pop();
      }
}

class Bird extends BaseClass {
    constructor(x,y){
      super(x,y,50,50);
    }
  
    display() {
      this.body.position.x = mouseX;
      this.body.position.y = mouseY;
      super.display();
    }
  }

  class Log extends BaseClass{
    constructor(x,y,height,angle){
      super(x,y,20,height,angle);
      Matter.Body.setAngle(this.body, angle);
    }
  }

  class Ground {
    constructor(x,y,width,height) {
      var options = {
          isStatic: true,
          density:10
      }
      this.body = Bodies.rectangle(x,y,width,height,options);
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      World.add(world, this.body);
    }
    display(){
      var pos =this.body.position;
      rectMode(CENTER);
      fill("brown");
      rect(pos.x, pos.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
  };

  class Chain{
    constructor(body1,body2){
        var constraint_options= {
            bodyA : body1.body,
            bodyB : body2.body,
            length: 5,
            stiffness : .002
        };
        this.constrainedObject= Constraint.create(constraint_options); 
        World.add(world,this.constrainedObject);
    };
    display(){
        var positionA= this.constrainedObject.bodyA.position;
        var positionB= this.constrainedObject.bodyB.position;
        strokeWeight(4);
        line(positionA.x,positionA.y,positionB.x,positionB.y);
    }
}


const Engine = Matter.Engine;
const World= Matter.World;
const Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
const Constraint = Matter.Constraint;

var engine, world;
var box1, pig1;
var platform,constrainedLog,birdLogConstraint,chain1;

function preload() {
}

function setup(){
    var canvas = createCanvas(1200,400);
    engine = Engine.create();
    world = engine.world;

    ground = new Ground(600,height,1200,20)
    platform= new Ground(100,250,300,400);
    //bird = new Bird(100,100);
    bird2 = new Bird(100,100);
   
    constrainedLog= new Log(230,180,80,PI/2);
    constrainedLog1= new Log(260,300,100,PI/2);
    
   chain1= new Chain(bird2,constrainedLog);
   chain2= new Chain(bird2,constrainedLog1);
}

function draw(){
    clear();
    Engine.update(engine);
    ground.display();
    platform.display();
    constrainedLog.display();
    constrainedLog1.display();
    chain1.display();
    chain2.display();
    bird2.display();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.14.2/matter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can i paste a github link to the code please?

Comment: okay sure, let m ego through this link and update you! taking your advise, thanks a tonne :)

Comment: i am a little confused as there are image files associated with this program too...

Comment: got it, that is done, but what about index.html,matter.js,p5 etc please? i have the rproducible code otherwise, i have put all that classes involved in the beginning of the same file and replaced all images by rectangle...

Comment: i was earlier on vsc editor...

Comment: Okay which means i should'nt have classes that inherit, but if  i dont do that and create bodies separately, the code might actually be longer? also i am adding snippets to the right section. should i put an entire cloudlink for matter.js, p5.play.js etc for tis to run in the HTML section?

Comment: But the whole problem might be because of the way matter.js treats the rectangle bodies, so it doesnt make sense to take it off? I have to work with matter.js in this project, hence...

Comment: Thanks for the update and full code. The problem is `this.body.position.x = mouseX;` which is overriding the MJS engine to put the bird at that exact x/y position regardless of any obstacles. Remove these lines and you'll see the collision works just fine. If you use [`applyForce`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#method_applyForce), you'll be able to add movement that will preserve collisions, either relative to the mouse position or the keyboard (Flappy Bird is usually keyboard/button/tap-driven rather than mouse location-based).

Comment: Thanks a tonne GGORLEN! I understood that, makes a lot of sense! :) just one last question, in this case, when i  create a second body, bird2, that one passes through too but goes behind the platform while bird1 is visible on the fore front of the platform. Any idea why that is please?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that problem you describe. If you take the above code, comment out the `this.body.position.x = mouseX` (and `y` as well), then uncomment `//bird = new Bird(100,100);` and finally add `bird.display()` in the `draw` function, both birds render and collide with the ground as I'd expect, so everything seems working. Is your code somehow different than these 3 changes?

Comment: No actually, on this code it works fine. Remember I had earlier told you i was working with images, I had this problem there; while using image of Matter.js.

Comment: As with the first problem, I'd have to see the code that causes the problem to be able to tell you what's going on. It's really hard to debug code without looking at a [mcve].